# Proof of the following condition

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand why equation (14) from  of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0247.pdf) from the section, `Introduction to analytic results`.
If

$\dot{W} = EA^{T}$   -- (12)

$\dot{A} = BE $   -- (13)

Show that $ BW + W^{T}B^{T} = AA^{T} + C$  -- (14)

Here $W, A, E, B$ are matrices represent weights of a neural network. They're assumed to be not square
matrices.

Multiply equation 12 by $B$ on the left and multiply equation 13 by $A^{T}$ on the right, we have

$\dot{A}A^{T} = B\dot{W}$ -- (15)

Integrating equation 15

$\int \dot{A}A^{T} dt = \int B\dot{W}dt + C_{1}$ -- (16)

Transposing equation 16

$\int A\dot{A}^{T} dt = \int \dot{W}^{T}B^{T} dt + C^{T}_{1}$ -- (17)

Then the author goes to say

$\int \dot{A}A^{T} dt = \int A\dot{A}^{T} dt = \frac{1}{2}AA^{T} + C$ -- (18)

I understood how the author derived equation 15, 16, 17. I'm not sure how equation 18 holds. I know that

$\dot{(AA^{T})} =  \dot{A}A^{T} + A\dot{A}^{T}$.

Can this relation be used to prove the equation 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the symmetrization operator as
$$\eqalign{
{\rm sym}(X) &= \tfrac{1}{2}(X+X^T) \\
}$$
Use the two known relations (yours and equation 15) to expand the following differential. 
$$\eqalign{
d(AA^T)
 &= dA\,A^T + A\,dA^T \\
 &= 2\,{\rm sym}(dA\,A^T) \\
 &= 2\,{\rm sym}(B\,dW) \\
}$$
Integrating both sides yields equation 14.
$$\eqalign{
\int d(AA^T) &= 2\,{\rm sym}(\int B\,dW) = 2\,{\rm sym}(B\int dW) \\
AA^T
 &= 2\,{\rm sym}(BW) + C \;=\; BW + W^TB^T + C \\
}$$

Comment: How did you get the idea to use symmetrization operator? Any signs to look for?

Comment: The operator isn't strictly necessary, it just makes things look nicer. The fewer symbols you have to keep in your head, the easier it is to follow the derivation.